# Local file path not found while download blob file using c#

Tags: c#, blob

I am new to blob storage. I am trying to download blob file. But I am facing an exception

> Access to the path 'C:\Users\xxx\Downloads' is denied.

Please share your view. Thanks in advance

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("connectionstring");
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("_report");
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("Report / report1 / YYY.pdf");            

// Save blob contents to a file.    
blockBlob.DownloadToStream(System.IO.File.OpenWrite(@"C:\Users\xxx\Downloads"));
```

Comment: My view is that whatever context this code is running doesn't have permission to that path. Unfortunately you've provided no information as to what this program is and how it runs.

Comment: What's the filename you're trying to "OpenWrite"? Where are you specifying that name? It looks like you may be trying to open a directory as a filestream..

Comment: The stream is trying to open "@"C:\Users\xxx\Downloads" as a file and on that location needs additional access-rights. You may want to change @"C:\Users\xxx\Downloads" to @"C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\somefile.txt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the last code line to the following:

```
        using (Stream str = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(@"C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\somefile.txt"))
        {
            blockBlob.DownloadToStream(str);
        }
```

The path is now pointing to a file in the downloads-directory. the previous value tried to create a file called downloads in C:\Users\xxx\

And please dispose your streams. (done with the using-keyword)

Comment: CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("Report / report1 / YYY.pdf"); In this code i am mentioning blob path. Is this right way? because i want to download a blob from sub folder.